# Java Arraylist.contains(Object) always returns false

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, contains, indexof

Basically i want to create a class "Screws". This class shall describe a Screw by Type, length, thickness etc. I also want to create a "storage" class, that stores said "Screws" in all variances. The type, length etc. is limited to 7 and 3 (so there will be a limited amount of possibilities)

```
public class Screws{
public Screws(int typ,double durchmesser,double laenge,double gangHoehe){
    this.schraubenArt = typ;
    this.durchmesser=durchmesser;
    this.laenge=laenge;
    this.gangHoehe=gangHoehe;
  }
}
```

Now i want to create a storage "unit", that will be an arraylist. I want to fill it with objects of "Screws". Afterwards i want to be able to check if a certain Scredobject is contained in the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lager {

private Screws schrauben;
private ArrayList<Screws>Kreuzschlitzlager;

public Lager(){
Kreuzschlitzlager = new ArrayList<>();

for(int durchmesser=0; durchmesser <=3; durchmesser++){
    for(int laenge=0; laenge <= 3; laenge++){
        for(int ganghoehe=0; ganghoehe <=3; ganghoehe++){
            Kreuzschlitzlager.add(new Screws (1,durchmesser,laenge,ganghoehe);); 
    }}}}

public boolean checkForObject(Screws object){
    return Kreuzschlitzlager.contains(object);
}
```

Now my problem is, i get a long list of objects i can "get" the properties of, but if i checkForObject(Anything) it will always give me a "false". I can't figure out why though. Don't worry about the class Screws, it's not nearly done. :D 
So, how do i check if an array list contains a certain object, why is it not working in this case and can i get the index of the object with .IndexOf?

Comment: You should implement proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Most of the IDEs can generate equals and hashCode for you if you dont want to write yourself.

Comment: what does .length() returns?

Answer (score 4):

You're right; the `Screws` class isn't done.  The [`ArrayList` class calls the `equals` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) to determine if the element is equal to the argument to `contains`, but you don't override `equals`.  Your `Screws` class is inheriting `equals` from `Object`, and it will only return `true` if it's the same exact object.

Override the `equals` method, signature `boolean equals(Object obj)` in `Screws`.  You will need to code the logic for determining equality yourself.

Additionally, the [contract for `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) means that it needs to be consistent with `hashCode`.  For this small application, it's not necessary, but generally you should also override `hashCode` to be consistent with `equals`.

Comment: Wait, so i basically have to add a method to screws that compares say getValue1 of the object in the list, to the object created in lager? Thanks a lot, i will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the javadoc for List.contains

> boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).
>
> Specified by:
>       contains in interface Collection
>
> Parameters:
>       o - element whose presence in this list is to be tested Returns:
>       true if this list contains the specified element
>
> Throws:
>       ClassCastException - if the type of the specified element is incompatible with this list (optional)
>       NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this list does not permit null elements (optional)

If you don't specify an equals method for your class Screws, it's going to check if they are the same object.  Define an equals method.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` method of ArrayList does this:

```
Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))
```

For example, we initialize two Screws objects which contains the exact values.

```
Screws screws1 = new Screws(1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
Screws screws2 = new Screws(1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
Kreuzschlitzlager.add(screws1);
Kreuzschlitzlager.contains(screws2);   // this returns false
```

It only compares the memory address by default. screws1 and screws2 have different memory addresses, so they are not the same object, and they are not equal. You have to override  `boolean equals(Object)` and `int hashcode()`  in your `Screws` class, define your own way how two Screws objects are equal

Comment: What does int hashcode() do in this case? I haven't heard about this before :) I got the method part though!

Comment: @Shenanigator good catch.  hashcode() only used in hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

in your `Screws` class, you need to override the method `equals(...)` and implement how two Screws should be equal